# Unable to close the form using Me.Form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

In vb.net ,unable to close the child form by ME.CLOSE.
On click of Me.Close , first execute - Me.Close statement and then execute - Me.Activate event and form gets open.
Now, again click on button, it will execute "me.Close" and then form gets closed.
Both the time, when i debug and check - "Me.IsDispose()" it shows true.

Below is the code of MDI which open that form:

```
   Dim f As New frm
    Try
        f.MdiParent = Me
        f.ID = 1
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        f.Show()
        f.BringToFront()
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        f= Nothing
    End Try
```

Now, in form f -, on button click event, i have written below code:

```
        Me.Close

        'tried each control to dispose prior close and also tried by Me.Dispose
```

PLease suggest what is wrong and how to trace this issue.

Comment: I do not understand the problem.

Comment: Does frm already exist as a windows form elsewhere in your project allowing you to create a new version of it.  If it does then set a breakpoint in the code of that.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `Me.Close`, does it even hit? If not, check if the `onClick` event is wired up correctly.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg    Me.Close line is called correctly as i have checked by adding break point. It shows Me.IsDisposed() return true after executing Me.Close and then it execute "Form Activate" Event and then back to end statement of Button click event. and form does not close. On next click, it close.

Comment: @DomSinclair ,NOt existed, it is only single form in application.

Answer (score 0):

`Me.Close` is all you should need to close the Form.

So either

1 - Something is loading your form again:

Put a breakpoint on `Form_Load` - does it get hit after `Me.Close`?

2 - There a thread on/in the form that is still running and preventing it from closing?

Put a breakpoint on `Me.Close` and view the active threads `Debug > Windows > Threads`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments.

Actually, the issue was, i had wrote below code:

In MDI form, to open form "frm" ("f). ,i wrote below code:

Addhandler toolstripmenu.click, addressOf toolstripmenu_click event.

```
      toolstripmenu_click(......) handles  toolstripmenu
      {  Dim f As New frm
Try
    f.MdiParent = Me
    f.ID = 1
    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    f.Show()
    f.BringToFront()
Catch ex As Exception
Finally
    f= Nothing
End Try
   }
```

So, the problem was, event handler was registered twise. First registered by (Addhandler toolstripmenu.click, addressOf toolstripmenu_click event) and second , already added handler over the event.
So, On close button, Me.Close was able to close the form on second time. (i don't know how ).
But, by removing handler from event and only keep - handler registeration code. It works fine.

Thanks
Dhaval